# How to convert a Hedera native address into an EVM address? ​

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hedera

How can I convert a **Hedera-native address** to an **EVM address** (and vice versa)?
​
Let's say I have the following:

- a Hedera-native account, with an address like  `0.0.12345`
- an EVM account on Hedera, with an address like `0xabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde`
  ​
  I would like to transfer some HBAR from my EVM account to my Hedera-native account.
  This implies, I think, that I would need to somehow convert the Hedera-native address to an EVM-address format.
  How can I do this?

Part 2 of this question is simply the above in reverse direction.
If I would like to transfer some HBAR from my Hedera-native account to my EVM account,
I would need to covert the EVM address to a Hedera-native address.
Is this also possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

​
The Hedera-native addresses take the format of `${shard}.${realm}.${number}`.
In practice, currently there is only one shard, and one realm,
both with the value of `0`, so you only need to convert the `number` component.
​
To do so simply convert `number` from decimal to hexadecimal,
and then pad it on the left with zeroes to get a 40 digit hexadecimal number.
​
Worked example with your address:
​

- `0.0.12345` --> `number` is `12345`
- `12345` in decimal is `0x3039` in hexadecimal
- Since `0x3039` has 4 digits, we need to pad with 36 zeroes, to make for 40 digits in total
- `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000` concatenated with `0x3039`
- `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000003039`
  ​
  Next, you can transfer HBAR from your EVM account
  to the address that you just converted (`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000003039`).
  Them check the balance of your Hedera-native account (`0.0.12345`),
  and you should have an updated HBAR balance.
  ​
  This works because under the hood,
  the Hedera networks treats the EVM address of this type as an alias for the Hedera-native account.
  See [HIP-583: Expand alias support in CryptoCreate & CryptoTransfer Transactions](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-improvement-proposal/blob/master/HIP/hip-583.md) where this is described:
  ​

> If a user is using an Ethereum-native wallet ... they cannot send hbars to a `shard.realm.num` account ID, they must send it to a 20-byte address.
>
> Every account in Hedera has an Ethereum compatible 20-byte `alias` (known as the “long zero” `alias` since it is prefixed by many zeros), and an Ethereum-native wallet using the JSON-RPC relay **can** use that to send value to existing accounts with no modification to the existing accounts.
> ​

---

​
***Detailed explanation***
​
In `EntityIdHelper` [of hedera-sdk-js](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/827e5e079de8fbe04f2915b7d14f0f08f7080ddb/src/EntityIdHelper.js#L217-L219), we have the following definition in the comments,
which identifies the exact mapping of all components of
Hedera-native addresses to EVM addresses.
​

> Solidity addresses are 20 bytes long and hex encoded, where the first 4
> bytes represent the shard, the next 8 bytes represent the realm, and
> the last 8 bytes represent the num. All in Big Endian format
> ​
> Using this description, we can convert, by hand, a Hedera-native account address
> into an EVM address.
> It can be summarised as:

- Convert decimal to hexadecimal, per component
- Pad the shard component on the left with zeroes to obtain a width of 8 digits
- Pad both the realm and number components on the left with zeroes to obtain a width of 16 digits
- Concatenate components

```
Hedera-native address pattern:
S.R.N
​
Hedera-native address example:
17.2049.12345
​
(Interrim step) Hedera-native address components in hexadecimal:
0x11 0x801 0x3039
​
EVM address pattern:
0xSSSSSSSSRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
​
EVM address example:
0x0000001100000000000008010000000000003039
​
```

Obviously, the above is just to illustrate the concept,
and this really isn't something you would want to do by hand.
So use the implementation within `hedera-sdk-js`:

- To convert from EVM address to Hedera-native address: [`fromSolidityAddress(address)`](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/827e5e079de8fbe04f2915b7d14f0f08f7080ddb/src/EntityIdHelper.js#L224-L239)
- To convert from Hedera-native address to EVM address: [`toSolidityAddress(address)`](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/827e5e079de8fbe04f2915b7d14f0f08f7080ddb/src/EntityIdHelper.js#L249-L259)

---

Created a code snippet out of this: [`hedera-dev/hedera-code-snippets/blob/main/convert-hedera-native-address-to-evm-address`](https://github.com/hedera-dev/hedera-code-snippets/blob/main/convert-hedera-native-address-to-evm-address/)