# How to convert a Hedera native address into a non-long-zero EVM address?

Tags: javascript, solidity, hedera-hashgraph

Using Hedera SDK JS, I can convert an Account ID to "long-zero" format EVM address.
e.g. `0.0.3996280` --> `0x00000000000000000000000000000000003cfa78`

(See related question: ["How to convert a Hedera native address into an EVM address?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76182999/194982).)

How do I convert to the "non-long-zero" format EVM address?
e.g. `0.0.3996280` --> `0x7394111093687e9710b7a7aeba3ba0f417c54474`

(See [`0.0.3996280` on Hashscan](https://hashscan.io/testnet/account/0.0.3996280).)

I need this because when you send `ContractCallQuery` via Hedera SDKs, the value of `msg.sender` as visible within any smart contract functions invoked is the "non-long-zero" format EVM address.

What I'm doing currently:

```js
const operatorId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_ID);
const operatorEvmAddress = operatorId.toSolidityAddress();
```

However, `operatorEvmAddress` is in the "long-zero" format,
and I therefore cannot use that in my subsequent smart contract interactions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you have access to the public key of the account.
Note that if you have the private key, you can extract the public key from it.
​
**If you *do not* have access to the account's public key**:
​
You can obtain the long-zero EVM address using the SDK,
as this is a mathematical conversion.
​
However, you cannot obtain the non-long-zero EVM address using the SDK alone,
as this is *not* a mathematical conversion.
You will need to query the network state,
for example through a Hedera mirror node query.
​
**If you *do* have access to the account's public key**:
​
You can obtain both the long-zero EVM address *and*
the non-long-zero EVM address using the SDK.
​

```js
const operatorId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_ID);
const operatorPrivateKey = PrivateKey.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_KEY);
const operatorPublicKey = operatorPrivateKey.publicKey;
​
// AccountId.toSolidityAddress --> long-zero
const operatorEvmAddressLongZero = operatorId.toSolidityAddress();
​
// PublicKey.toEvmAddress --> non-long-zero
const operatorEvmAddressNonLongZero = operatorPublicKey.toEvmAddress();
```

Comment: Good answer! Welcome to SO.  (And ... this answer could be improved if you add the REST call to the mirror node you allude to for the no-public-key case...)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Ashe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682765/194982), and requested in [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76680532/how-to-convert-a-hedera-native-address-into-a-non-long-zero-evm-address/76763434#comment135196366_76682765):

> If you do not have access to the account's public key
> ...
> You will need to query the network state, for example through a Hedera mirror node query.​

Here is one way to do it, via the mirror node:

```bash
curl \
  --silent \
  -X 'GET' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  'https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/accounts/0.0.3996280?limit=1' \
  | jq --raw-output ".evm_address"
```

This will output:

```
0x7394111093687e9710b7a7aeba3ba0f417c54474
```

which is indeed the non-long-zero EVM address that corresponds to this account.

---

Ref: Mirror Node Swagger for the above API:
https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/docs/#/accounts/getAccountByIdOrAliasOrEvmAddress